# Conditional compilation techniques in C# to get no-op results

Tags: c#, optimization, c-preprocessor, conditional-compilation

Does anyone know a good way (either through reflection or special attributes) to replace certain functions calls with no-ops in C#?

Basically, what I'm trying to do is something like this

```
#ifdef DEBUG

StopWatch.start();

#endif

DoSomething();

#ifdef DEBUG

StopWatch.stop();
Log.TimingInfo(StopWatch);

#endif
```

without sprinkling a lot of ifdefs everywhere in my code. I could replace this (my StopWatch class) with a null object pattern and assign it the null object conditionally, but this is still not ideal compared to strictly no-op in the code. The code path length is very important here, and i'd rather sacrifice some read-ability for having absolutely no op when we're not trying to collect timing results.

Does anyone know if there is a way to tag my StopWatch class or methods in C# to simply not emit code when evaluated by the compiler?

Comment: How about using a profiler tool instead?

Comment: we are timing our methods using hardware events exposed by the intel chips, software timing, and network packet capture at the switch level. they are all used collectively. we want a flexible way to add and remove the software timing code without uglifying the codebase with #ifdefs.

Answer (score 11):

You can annotate your methods with the `[Conditional("DEBUG")]` attribute like:

```
class StopWatch
{
    [Conditional("DEBUG")]
    public void Start() { }

    [Conditional("DEBUG")]
    public void Stop() { }
}
```

This has the same effect as `#ifdef DEBUG` around calls to `Start`/`Stop`. One caveat: conditional methods must return void. There are a few other restrictions as well. See the [ConditonalAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664622(VS.71).aspx) documentation for details.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea you could do this.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on C# 3.0 or later, you could look into partial methods:

http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2007/07/28/c-3-0-partial-methods-what-why-and-how.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use such class, it also includes logging to visual studio's output window:

```
public static class TimerCalls
{
    private static Dictionary _Stopwatches = new Dictionary();

    [ConditionalAttribute("TIMERS")]
    public static void StartStopwatch(string key)
    {
        if (_Stopwatches.ContainsKey(key)) //Stopwatch already running
            return;

        _Stopwatches.Add(key, Stopwatch.StartNew());
    }

    [ConditionalAttribute("TIMERS")]
    public static void StopStopwatch(string key)
    {
        if (!_Stopwatches.ContainsKey(key))//No such stopwatch currently
            return;

        var watch = _Stopwatches[key];
        watch.Stop();
        _Stopwatches.Remove(key);
        Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Timer: {0}, {1}ms ---- {2}", key,
            watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds, DateTime.Now));
    }
}
```

And "how to use":

```
TimerCalls.StartStopwatch("Operations");
// many operations..
TimerCalls.StopStopwatch("Operations");// Timer: Operations, 508ms ---- 27.06.2012 11:41:06
```

It uses conditional symbol TIMERS that can be added to your program via visual studio project properties or with #define(sure you will need to deal with the class creation time penalties).
You can read more in my [blog post](http://0x49d1.net/?p=457) about that. But its in russian.